# CSS - Webpage Screen remains at a large size when in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, mobile, scaling

[Screen Size unchanged on Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCW1O.png)

Briefly explaining this, I have a Chat App that works well on a desktop view but when we go into mobile it seems that the device simply mimics the size of the desktop screen (ie: on my Oneplus 6 the `<html>` tag is around 4000x2000px). I'm quite new to HTML mobile scaling so forgive me if the wording for this isn't to par with what's expected.

Continuing, on my desktop if I manually change Chrome's window size my webpage scales perfectly while on my mobile device it's huge as said in the previous line. Would using the `@media` tag in css help specifically for this? If so, how?

One last thing, if I zoom in manually on my mobile it obviously looks perfect as it's meant to fit the new tall aspect ratios. Which is ultimately what I wish to do, just need to keep the website scaled perfectly like on the second picture (picture B).[Image B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciAoi.png)

Comment: Try adding this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to the `<head>`

Comment: Perfect it was exactly that! Cheers!